# Twilio REST Client stops working after adding Studio Flow?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio REST client in Visual Studio 2017. After adding a Studio Flow for a [simple SMS autoresponder](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-set-up-auto-responder), I am no longer able to use the Twilio REST API to send a SMS message from my ASP.net app.

The error message is "Upgrade Required"

```
at Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient.ProcessReponse(Reponse response)
at Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageResource.Create(CreateMessageOptions options, ITwilioRestClient client)
at...
```

I already tried upgrading the Twilio REST API helper library NuGet package to latest, version 5.28.0.

The error occurs on this basic SMS sending code that used to work.

```
Dim message = MessageResource.Create(body:=strBody, from:=New Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(Credentials.TwilioFixityNewNumberFormatted), [to]:=New Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(strFormattedNumber))
Return message.Sid
```

There are no error messages or notifications in my Twilio account that something is wrong or needed. Has anyone experienced something like this?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you did as to "adding a Studio Flow". If you revert whatever you did, are you then able to send messages again?

Comment: No, I can't revert. I simply followed the guide in the link. After examining the exception it appears to be API error 20426 and/or 20011. The accompanying documentation says that new TLS 1.2 requirements go in effect for new projects created after 3/28/19. My guess is that adding the Flow made the project "new" and subject to these new requirements that my HTTP client currently cannot handle.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007724794-Notice-Twilio-REST-API-s-TLS-and-Cipher-Suite-Security-Changes-for-June-2019

Answer (score 3):

It seems that modifying the Twilio project made it a "new" project subject to TLS 1.2 requirements that were just implemented on 3/28/19. The problem was solved by updating Windows and .NET to the latest updates, and explicitly enabling TLS 1.2 prior to accessing the Twilio REST API:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12   'Force TLS 1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio returns *Upgrade Required* when you use an old TLS version. Setting the version directly using `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` does fix it, but it's not a good idea since it'll become outdated when a new TLS version is released. Instead, see *[Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)* for some reasons it may be selecting an older version.

In my case it was due to this line in `Web.config`:

```xml
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Setting it to the actual .NET Framework version I'm using fixed the Twilio error.