# I'm getting error Upgrade Required while integrating twilio whatsapp in c#

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

This is the error I am  getting while trying to send the message.

> An unhandled exception of type 'Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException'
>   occurred in Twilio.dll
>       Additional information: Upgrade Required

My code is:

```
const string accountSid = "Value";
const string authToken = "Value";
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var to = new PhoneNumber("+whatsapp:+13233633791");
var message = MessageResource.Create(
    to,
    from: new PhoneNumber("+whatsapp:+12037179461"),
    body: "Hi Joe! Your order D45987AB will arrive on 8/12/2018 before 8 pm.");
    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
```

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428324/twilio-rest-client-stops-working-after-adding-studio-flow#comment97585161_55428324

Answer (score 21):

Per their docs, Twilio APIs now requires TLS v1.2 and string cipher suites.

Inside your method, before MessageResource.Create() is invoked, add

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Answer (score 10):

I was able to resolve this by setting :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; //TLS 1.2
```

in the start of my application.

You Can Also Read this github link issues:
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/472

Comment: Thank you so much, After struggling of so much tries finally this is solution saves my time

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the .Netframework to 4.7.1  of my application. and its working now